# Angular Unit Test: Error: Unexpected request: GET

Tags: angularjs, unit-testing, karma-jasmine

How can test this type of http format below?

```
$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'https://api.github.com/user/repos',
    headers:{
        'Authorization': "Basic " + btoa("xxxx:xxxx"),
        'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose'
    }
})
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.valid = true;
    $scope.collection = data;
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.error = data;
});
```

Test code,

```
it('should demonstrate using when (200 status)', inject(function($http, $httpBackend) {

    var $scope = {};

    /* Code Under Test */
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'https://api.github.com/user/repos',
        headers:{
            'Authorization': "Basic " + btoa("xxxxx:xxxx"),
            'Accept': 'application/json; odata=verbose'
        }
    })
    .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.valid = true;
        $scope.collection = data;
    })
    .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
        $scope.error = data;
    });
    /* End */

  $httpBackend
    .when('GET', 'https://api.github.com/user/repos', undefined, {
        Authorization: "Basic " + btoa("xxxxx:xxxx"),
        Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
    })
    .respond(200, { foo: 'bar' });

  $httpBackend.flush();

  expect($scope.valid).toBe(true);
  expect($scope.collection).toEqual({ foo: 'bar' });

}));
```

I get this error,

> Error: Unexpected request: GET https://api.github.com/user/repos No
>   more request expected

Any ideas?

Comment: shouldn't the `.when('GET', 'https://api.github.com/user/repos'` be before the actuall call?

Comment: how come? I'm following this guide http://www.bradoncode.com/blog/2015/06/26/unit-testing-http-ngmock-fundamentals/

Comment: The catch for `$http` calls should be defined before the actual call is made, move the `$httpBackend` before `$http()`

Comment: did that but no difference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

can you try this

```
$httpBackend.whenGET('https://api.github.com/user/repos', undefined, {
    Authorization: "Basic " + btoa("xxxxx:xxxx"),
    Accept: "application/json;odata=verbose"
}).respond(function(){ return [200,[{foo: 'bar' }]]});
```

Comment: @teelou, basically  $httpbackend's respond method can take two versions one is 1) function returning an array of status, data and header info etc and the second one is set of static data containing status and data etc.         Although in the function version the status is mandatory.